# Is Redis a good idea for Spring Cloud Stream? Should I use Kafka or RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I'm deploying a small Spring Cloud Stream project, 
using only http sources and jdbc sinks (3 instances each). The estimated load is 10 hits/second.

I was thinking on using redis because I feel more confortable with it, but in the latest documentation almost all the refereces are to kafka and RabbitMQ so I am wondering if redis is not going to be supported in the future or if there is any issue using redis.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis is not recommended for production with Spring Cloud Stream - the binder is not fully functional and message loss is possible.

Comment: To be fair - message loss is also possible with RabbitMQ at its default settings. I learn this the hard way recently in a production environment. With RabbitMQ you have to use set the queue to be transactional=true, which reduces performance by a factor of 250. There is also another mechanism called producer confirms but last time I checked it is not supported by Spring Cloud Stream. Seems like the way to go is only Kafka at this point.

Comment: @odedia Using publisher confirms for a single send is not much different to using transactions. It really only comes into its own (performance wise) when you send a bunch of messages than wait for all the confirms. Pretty much the only stream app that would benefit from it would be the splitter, which produces multiple outputs from one input.